# Css + jQuery dropdown submenu overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a css menu as shown in the picture:
[image]

When I put the mouse over "Haschildren" I obtain:
[image]

My question is: what shall I modify to avoid the overflow (the grey all-around the sub-voices)? I tried to modify the ul e li properties in the css, but with no results... I want to change only the strict necessary, leaving unaltered all the rest.

The HTML snippet is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.has-children').hover(
    function() {
      $(".sub-menu li").slideDown("slow");

    });

  $(".sub-menu").mouseleave(function() {
    $('.sub-menu li').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.header li {
  float: left;
}
.submenu ul {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.sub-menu li {
  clear: both;
  display: none;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  clear: both;
  border-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
  
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#work">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="has-children" href="#about">Haschildren</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#link1">Child 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#link2">Child 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#link3">Child 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented out two lines and added background-color to `.header li a`:

```
.header {
   background-color: #333;
   /*position: absolute;*/
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 3;
}
.header ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   /*overflow: hidden;*/
   background-color: #333;
}
.header li a {
   display: block;
   padding: 20px 20px;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #333;
}
.header li {
   float: left;
}
.submenu ul {
   background-color: #fff;
}
.sub-menu li {
   clear: both;
   display: none;
}
.sub-menu li a {
   clear: both;
   border-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: The only thing you need to check is whether it affects the content that will be below. But in such case you need to set the height of the menu bar so that it does not increase when the menu items drop down. Let me know if you need help with this. BTW,  I think there is a way to achieve dropdown menu even without jquery, with css alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `.has-children` li parent relative and make the `.submenu` absolute. You can then position the submenu with `top, left` etc. properties to fit your design

Comment: I tried ` .menu ul{
   position:relative;
   }
   
   .submenu {position: absolute;}
  
  .submenu ul {
 position: absolute;
 
   }` but seems to do nothing...

Comment: use `.menu` and `.submenu` since your declaration doesn't match any element in your HTML

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ul class="top-level-menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a>
     <ul class="second-level-menu">
        <li><a href="#">History of the organisation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Objective of the company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
    </ul>
```

```css
.third-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -150px;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.third-level-menu > li {
    background: #3a3836;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;width: 135%;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.second-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}
.second-level-menu > li a{
    font-family: 'FuturaBT-Medium', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;    text-transform: none;}
.second-level-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    background: #231f1c;
    z-index: 9999999;
    text-align: left;width: 140%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.top-level-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 154px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    display: inline;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-left: 1px solid;background-color: #231f1c;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover {    background: #f4821e;
}

.top-level-menu li:hover > ul
{
    /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
    display: inline;
}


/* Menu Link Styles */

.top-level-menu a /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
{
    font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    
    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
       <body>
          
                <ul class="top-level-menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
      <ul class="second-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#">History of the organisation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Objective of the company</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
        </ul>

           
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer I set the menu position absolute and submenu li position relative. And also use left right 0 and top: 40   to equal the line-height of the links. Also [liveFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/ht4haxcj/5/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.has-children').hover(
    function() {
      $(".sub-menu li").slideDown("slow");

    });

  $(".sub-menu").mouseleave(function() {
    $('.sub-menu li').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
 

   header {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}


/* sub navigation */

.menu li ul {
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
  /* make this equal to the line-height of the links (specified below) */
  right: 0;
}

.menu a {
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin: 0 12px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.menu a:hover,
.menu a:focus,
.menu a:active {
  color: #bbb;
}


/* style sub level links */

.sub-menu li a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.sub-menu li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
   display: none; /* hide sub with css */
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<header class="header">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a class="has-children" href="#about">Haschildren</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#link1">Child 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link2">Child 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link3">Child 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works, +1, but you changed a lot from my original.. I  would like to change only where really necessary to avoid the extra large size in grey, if possible, maintaining inalterate all the rest...

Comment: yes but I have make some changes  in css which is easy for understand. But I just dont add the border color. In you last edit on css .submenu ul which is not a valid in css selector.